# How to change the actual argument passed to a function in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I want to change the actual argument passed to a function and not a copy of it. For example:

```
char str[] = "This is a string";
```

I want to create a function after a call to which the value of `str` is different. I tried to create a function accepting `char**` as the argument but I just couldn't get what I want.

Comment: Showing us what you tried would help you get a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean something like this:

```
void update_string(char ** ptr)
{
    *ptr = strdup("This is a test");
    return;
}
```

Then call the function like this:

```
char * str = strdup("hello world\n");
printf("%s\n", str);
update_string(&str);
printf("%s\n", str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may pass `char*`. The pointer *will* be copied, but it will still point to the same string

If you need the pointer itself to be passed (not its copy) you should pass a `char**`

Answer (score 0):

To change a string passed to a function in-place, use a regular pointer. For example:

```
void lower_first_char(char *str)
{
    *str = tolower(*str);
}
```

After this function executes, the first character of the passed string will be changed to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a `char*` if you want to modify the actual string:

```
foo(str);
...
void foo(char *some_string) {
   some_string[0] = 'A';
}
```

`str` will now **hold** `"Ahis is a string"`

If instead of `str` being an array, you had: `char *str = "Hello";`, and wanted to modify where `str` *pointed*, then you would pass a `char**`:

```
bar(&str);
...
void bar(char **ptr_string) {
   *ptr_string = "Bye";
}
```

`str` will now **point** to `"Bye"`.