# C - segmentation fault when accessing a pointer in header file

Tags: c, pointers, header, dynamic-allocation

I'm programming in C, and have two files, **func2.h**:

```
#define NN 20

void network_construction(int **veins, int *num_veins){

        int i, j;


        for(i=0;i<NN;i++){
            num_veins[i] = NN/2;
        }


        veins = malloc(NN * sizeof(*veins));
        for (i = 0; i < NN; i++) { veins[i] = malloc(num_veins[i] * sizeof(*(veins[i]))); }
        for (i = 0; i < NN; i++) { for (j = 0; j<num_veins[i];j++) { veins[i][j] = -1; } }


    return;
    }
```

and **main.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "func2.h"

void main(){

    int num_veins[NN];
    int **veins;


    network_construction(veins, num_veins);

    printf("\n%d\n", num_veins[19]);
    printf("\n%d\n", veins[2][2]);

return;
}
```

num_veins[] gives the right number, 10, but when trying to access to any elements of veins, it gives segmentation fault. How can I use in main.c the values of veins that are filled in func2.h ? What am I doing wrong and why is this happening ?

**EDIT:**

These codes are a simplified version of bigger ones. In the answers there is a way to solve the problem, but it is not exactly what I want. What I need is to do the dynamic allocation in `func2.h`, so I don't want any calculation involving veins[][] in `main.c` before the call to network_construction().

Comment: you can start with putting the function definition in `.c` file.

Comment: ..and possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8543808/2173917)

Comment: So, @SouravGhosh, I do that and then what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below achieves what I wanted:

```
void network_construction(int ***veins, int num_veins[]){
  int i,j;

  for(i=0;i<NN;i++){
    num_veins[i] = NN/2;
  }

  (*veins) = malloc((NN) * sizeof(**veins));

  for(i=0;i<NN;i++){
    (*veins)[i] = malloc(num_veins[i]*sizeof(*(*veins)[i]));
  }

  for (i = 0; i < NN; i++) { 
    for (j = 0; j < num_veins[i]; j++) {
      (*veins)[i][j] = -1; 
    }
  }
  return;}
```

To call it in main():

```
network_construction(&veins,num_veins);
```

Answer (score 0):

`veins = malloc(NN * sizeof(*veins));` is your problem.
You actually need an `int***` to do what you want.
Inside `network_construction`, the argument veins is actually a copy of the variable `veins` in your `main`. Therefore when you malloc it, only the copy changes, but not the variable in main.

A simpler example of the same problem would be this:

```
void foo(int a){
    a=5;
}
void foo2(int* a){
    *a=5;
}
int main(){
    int a=0;
    foo(a);
    printf("%d\n",a);
    foo2(&a);
    printf("%d\n",a);
}
```

which prints `0` `5`. Your case is the same, but instead of `int` and `int*`, think of `int**` and `int***`

Comment: I appreciate your help, @Cantfindname, but with the information you give me I have not been able to solve the problem yet. I edited the question to clarify what I want. Could you take a look to it and the other comments/answers and see if you come up with an idea to solve the problem ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Your function call should be as follows:

network_construction(&veins, num_veins);

Then in the function network_construction catch veins as follows:

```
void network_construction(int ***veins, int *num_veins){

        int i, j;


        for(i=0;i<NN;i++){
            num_veins[i] = NN/2;
        }


        *veins = malloc(NN * sizeof(**veins));
        for (i = 0; i < NN; i++) { *veins[i] = malloc(num_veins[i] * sizeof(**(veins[i]))); }
        for (i = 0; i < NN; i++) { for (j = 0; j<num_veins[i];j++) { *veins[i][j] = -1; } }


    return;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @rajasekar25. Using your suggestion, it gives the error "func2.h:15:76: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]". Line 15 is where I assign the value -1 to my veins[i][j] elements. What should I do ?

Comment: you have to use it as "*veins[i][j]". Also if anywhere veins is occurring you need to add one *(dereference) before that.

Comment: Thanks again, now using *veins[i][j] the program compiles but when running it gives Segmentation fault. I am rookie in using pointers, so I'm not sure what "add one *(redeference) means. Do I have to include an * before every veins ? Because I tried that and it is still giving Segmentation Fault error.

Comment: I had modified the answer look for the new one

Comment: Also using function definition inside header file is bad style try to create a separate and file for function definition

Comment: Copying and pasting your code and using the same main.c file I posted above, without the printf statements and calling the function as network_construction(&veins, num_veins);, it gives me again Segmentation Fault. Is the code working in your computer ? Thanks a lot for your time, I would upvote your comments but my reputation isn't high enough...

Comment: In main did you changed function call as follows:

network_construction(&veins, num_veins);

Comment: Yes, I made that change, in main.c is written network_construction(&veins, num_veins);. I'm compiling and running with gcc main.c and ./a.out, if useful...

Comment: Ya its causing seg fault as follows:

0x00000000004005a9 in network_construction (veins=0x7fffffffda68, num_veins=0x7fffffffda70) at ptr.c:17

It is because the program is trying to allocate memory in next page which is not allocated to it. I will think of a solution for this and will update here if I got means.

Answer (score 0):

Your malloc in network_construction() function is the problem. Easy to overcome this thing is to modify your functions as follows:

Your func.c should be as follows:

```
 #define NN 20

    void network_construction(int **veins, int *num_veins){

            int i, j;

           for (i = 0; i < NN; i++) { for (j = 0; j<num_veins[i];j++) { veins[i][j] = -1; } }


        return;
        }
```

Your main function will be as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "func2.h"

void main(){

    int num_veins[NN];
    int **veins;
int i;


        for(i=0;i<NN;i++){
            num_veins[i] = NN/2;
        }


        veins = malloc(NN * sizeof(*veins));
        for (i = 0; i < NN; i++) { veins[i] = malloc(num_veins[i] * sizeof(*(veins[i]))); }

    network_construction(veins, num_veins);

    printf("\n%d\n", num_veins[19]);
    printf("\n%d\n", veins[2][2]);

return;
}
```

Comment: thanks, this indeed solves the problem. I had already thought about it, actually. However, these posted codes are simplified versions of a bigger one. In func2.h I'm doing more stuff in order to obtain num_veins[i], which are not constant entries. So I would really like to have all the calculations together in func2.h and use directly veins[][] in main.c, without  unnecessary calculations involving veins[][] before the call to network_construction(). Any idea in how to deal with it ?