# Assigning arrays to function pointer arguments in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm declaring pointers before my function call and want to get arrays when the function is executed. I followed the question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543808/how-to-change-the-actual-argument-passed-to-a-function-in-c) to obtain the following code

```
double *x;
double *y;
myfunction(1.0,&x,&y);
printf("x[0] = %1.1f\n",x[0] );
```

Where myfunction is

```
void myfunction(double data, double **x, double **y){
    /* Some code */
    int calculated_size = 10;
    *x = malloc(calculated_size*sizeof(double));
    *y = malloc(calculated_size*sizeof(double));
    int k;
    for (k = 0;k < calculated_size; k++)
    {
        *x[k] = k ;
        *y[k] = k ;
    }
```

}

Which gives me a segmentation fault as soon as it tries to assign

```
*x[k] = k;
```

Could someone indicate the exact way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `*x[k] = k ;` with `(*x)[k] = k ;` or better use as shown below

```
int *xa = *x;
xa[k] = k ;
```

`[]` binds tighter than `*` in C Operator precedence table causing the fault.

You expect : `(*x)[k]`
But you get: `*(x[k])`

[Live example](http://ideone.com/rDTEhF)

Comment: You can also do `*(*x + k) = k` and `*(*y + k) = k` as an alternative syntax.

Comment: Wonderful! Drives me crazy how long I was looking for a mistake like this... Thank you